# Javascript shorthand - array

Tags: javascript

Can someoyne please tell me, what is happening here ?

```
Array(+(r=readline)())
```

What the meaning of '+' in this statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It creates a new array with the result of the `readline()` function, and sets `r` to be a reference to the same function

```js
var readline = function() {
    return "3";
}

var arr = Array(+(r=readline)());

console.log(arr); // an array with 3 undefined
```

To break it up a little more

```js
var readline = function() {
    return "3";
}

var r;

var x = (r = readline);// returns "readline" as assigning always returns assigned value
var y = +x(); // returns whatever "readline" returns, and coerces into a number (3)
    
var arr = Array(y); // creates a number, "y" is now the number 3

console.log(arr); // an array with 3 undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The '+' is a javascript shorthand to cast to integer.
You could use "parseInt()" in place.

- **With the '+'** the code will convert the input to a number 'n' and create an array of 'n' empty entries
- **Without the '+'** the code will create an array of 1 entry containing 'n' as a string value